# PYTHON: A variable "a" changing value when applying a function to assign value to another variable such that b = func(a)

Tags: python

I am having trouble with a problem in python. I am making a tic tac toe game, i have created a function that takes in a list of lists containing the state of the game such that [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] and output a similar list replacing the 0, 1, 2 by "-", "X", "O" respectively as such -

```
def display_board(b):
    for r in range(0, 3):
        for c in range(0, 3):
            if b[r][c] == 1:
                b[r][c] = 'X'
            elif b[r][c] == 2:
                b[r][c] = 'O'
            else:
                b[r][c] = '-'
    return b
```

I am using as disp = display_board(b) where b contains the board state as mentioned above. The function is returning the needed value correctly, however, the value of b is also changing the same as disp. Also if there is another variable before this such that test = b the value of test also changes.

i have tried different compilers on different computers and the problem persists.
following is my full code and i am grateful for any help in advance

```
def move_input(p):
    x = str(input("player {} enter your move <row,col> - ".format(p)))
    while True:
        l = x.split(",")

        if len(x) != 3:
            x = str(input("ERROR: INVALID INPUT\please enter correct input row and col with comma in between <row,"
                          "col> - "))

        elif not (l[0].isdigit() and l[1].isdigit()):
            x = str(input("ERROR: INVALID INPUT\please enter correct input row and col with comma in between <row,"
                          "col> - "))

        else:
            x[0] -= 1
            x[1] -= 1
            return x

def display_board(a):
    b = a
    for r in range(0, 3):
        for c in range(0, 3):
            if b[r][c] == 1:
                b[r][c] = 'X'
            elif b[r][c] == 2:
                b[r][c] = 'O'
            else:
                b[r][c] = '-'
    return b


def game():
    g = [[0 for x in range(0, 3)] for x in range(0, 3)]
    print("Hi there! welcome to the game of tic tac toe...")

    while True:
        # Here is the problem
        print(g)
        disp = display_board(g) # the value of g changes after this
        print(g)
        print("\n{}\n{}\n{}".format(disp[0], disp[1], disp[2]))

        for player in range(1, 3):

            if (0 in g[0]) or (0 in g[1]) or (0 in g[2]):

                i = move_input(player)
                row = i[0]
                col = i[1]
                g[row][col] = player


            else:
                print("DRAW! good job both players")
                return 0


game()
```

Comment: `display_board` is somewhat misnamed: it's *modifying* the board, not simply displaying it.

Comment: _The function is returning the needed value correctly, however, the value of b is also changing the same as disp._ Yes, because lists are mutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b = a
```

Does not copy the contents of `a` into `b`. Both `a` & `b` are referring to the same underlying object after this. So if you modify it via `b`, `a` is also affected.

To make a copy, try:

```
from copy import deepcopy
...
b = deepcopy(a)
```

Output after this change:

```
before display: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
after diaplay: [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Oh right you have a nested list. You need `deepcopy`

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Depends on what exactly `copy()` does?  Is it a shallow copy or a deep copy?  If `g` references several objects, and those objects are also referenced by `disp`, that's a "shallow copy".  If 'g'` references several objects and all those objects are also copied (and so on), that's a "deep copy".

Comment: i did the following - 
    disp = g.copy()
    disp = display_board(disp) # the value of g still changes after this'

Comment: @DipanshuShukla please try deepcopy as suggested in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new list to return:

```
player_map = {1: 'X', 2: 'O'}

def make_display_board(a):
    return [[player_map.get(p, '-') for p in row] for row in a]
```